# Openserver SMTP сервер

Tags: php, smtp, openserver

Добрый день, можно как то на ходу в php менять логин и пароль для смтп авторизации ?

может ini_set или....

**UPD**

```
 ini_set('auth_username'); 
 ini_set('auth_password'); 
 ini_set("SMTP"); 
 ini_set("smtp_port");
 ini_set("sendmail_from");
```

Не имеют влияния .

Более того нельзя даже поставить свои настройки в php.ini т.к с каждым перезапуском open server перезаписывает блок [mail]

Comment: через что вы работаете то с smtp ?

Comment: Пакет openServer, настроил отправку через удаленный smtp 
как я вижу за настройку почты отвечает C:\OpenServer\modules\sendmail\senmail.ini
используя ini_set() что бы его изменить нечего не выходит.

Comment: почта доходит только если отправитель = логин. а мне нужно от разных отправителей.

Comment: дак как почту то отправляете саму? `mail()` там или еще чего.

Comment: mail()
через альтернативные классы не отправляются.